# Inserting div after first paragraph, but not a paragraph in a blockquote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which is working perfectly:

```
$('.container p').eq(2).after( $('.inserted') );
```

However, if the first paragraph is in a blockquote, some styling issues occur and I need to avoid that. So I need to change the code so that if a blockquote is present at the top of the page, to move the .inserted div to after the blockquote.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try:

```
var obj = $('.container p').eq(2);
if($('.container p').eq(2).parents("blockquote").length) 
    obj = $('.container p').eq(2).parents("blockquote");
obj.after( $('.inserted') );
```

You'll find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hyunkeln/k0hq6a46/6/

What this script does is look if the selected paragraph is a child from a blockquote, if so, then the inserted div goes right after the blockquote instead of the selected paragraph.

Comment: That worked! Thanks hyunkein, I'd upvote you but I'm not allowed to yet :)

Comment: hey man, just a reminder for the upvote. I'm still growing my status up, so... it would be cool, you know? cheers!

Comment: Hey man. I would, but I'm not allowed to upvote yet. I need more rep.

Comment: Also, after playing with it for a while I've noticed on problem. The code works perfectly when there is a blockquote present, but when there isn't a blockquote present, the .inserted div doesn't move at all.

Comment: You are right Jeph, the code is corrected now, I also noticed the fiddle wasn't updated, please check it out again. Don't worry for the upvote, it's cool to help you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on hyunkeln's code, I came up with this and this works 100% of the time:

```
$(function() {
    var $graphs     = $('.container p'),
        elem        = $graphs.eq(3),
        hasImage    = Boolean( $graphs.eq(3).parents('blockquote').length );

    if ( hasImage ) {
        elem = $graphs.eq(3).parents('blockquote');
    }
    elem.after( $('.inserted') );
});
```